# PHP mkdir does returns error even if directory exists

Tags: php, directory, mkdir

I have looked around these links

[Why does PHP think this folder doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134550/why-does-php-think-this-folder-doesnt-exist)

[No such file or directory error using mkdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970722/no-such-file-or-directory-error-using-mkdir)

and these solutions haven't worked for me. I still get Message: mkdir(): No such file or directory

I want to create a directory called 2018 with a subfolder 01 in a directory called folder_name. This is the path from the root when I enter $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']:
 "/home/digits/www.url.com/app"

This is what I have tried

```
    $document_folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".REPORT_FOLDER."/".date("Y")."/".date("m");

if(!is_dir($document_folder)){
     mkdir($document_folder, 0777);
}
```

Could someone take a look at this and see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Did you `echo` out your `$document_folder` to see if it is the correct path?

Comment: It generates "/home/digits/www.url.com/app/2018/01"

Comment: try checking what ever in REPORT_FOLDER exist in server and also check the permissions.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the `2018` folder doesn't exist.

To automatically create both, the `2018` and the `2018/01`folder, you need to pass `true` for `$recursive` ([PHP: mkdir](https://secure.php.net/mkdir))

```
mkdir($document_folder, 0777, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent directory of the directory you're trying to create must exist. I.e. the path up to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".REPORT_FOLDER."/".date("Y")."/"` must exist for you to create the directory `date("m")` within it.

You can use the `$recursive` parameter to have all the parent directories created implicitly:

```
mkdir($document_folder, 0777, true);
```

Comment: Ah! I assumed that mkdir would do that automatically. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes. Thank you!